# Из MainActivity не вызывается getView метод адаптер

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

Добрый день. Я учусь программировать приложения под андроид и в одной из книг нашел обучающий мануал - создание приложения прогноза погоды. Я следовал мануалу, но в конечном итоге заметил следующее: мое приложение справляется с задачей получения json-файла, парсит его и создает элементы списка с нужными значениями, но вот только адаптер никак не отображает мои элементы списка. Я прошелся отладчиком по всем методам проекта и заметил, что getView метод адаптера никогда не вызывается. Я много раз сравнивал его с тем приложением, которое у меня должно было выйти, но так и не нашел существенного отличия.

Как приложение должно себя вести после нажатия на кнопку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как оно ведет себя в моем случае:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:
MainActivity.java:

```
package ru.rarescrap.educationweatherview;

// MainActivity.java
// Вывод 16-дневного прогноза погоды для заданного города

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager; // Для сокрытия клавиатуры по нажатию FAB
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // Список объектов Weather, представляющих прогноз погоды
    private List<Weather> weatherList = new ArrayList<>();

    // ArrayAdapter связывает объекты Weather с элементами ListView
    private WeatherArrayAdapter weatherArrayAdapter;
    private ListView weatherListView; // Для вывода информации

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Сгенерированный код для заполнения макета и настройки Toolbar
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // ArrayAdapter для связывания weatherList с weatherListView
        weatherListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.weatherListView);
        weatherArrayAdapter = new WeatherArrayAdapter(this, weatherList);
        weatherListView.setAdapter(weatherArrayAdapter);

        // FAB скрывает клавиатуру и выдает запрос к веб-сервису
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Получить текст из locationEditText и создать URL веб-сервисы
                EditText locationEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.locationEditText);
                URL url = createURL(locationEditText.getText().toString());

                // Скрыть клавиатуру и запустить GetWeatherTask для получения
                // погодных данных от OpenWeatherMap.org в отдельном потоке
                if (url != null) {
                    dismissKeyboard(locationEditText);
                    GetWeatherTask getLocalWeatherTask = new GetWeatherTask();
                    getLocalWeatherTask.execute(url);
                }else {
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout),
                            R.string.invalid_url, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // Клавиатура закрывается при касании кнопки FAB
    private void dismissKeyboard(View view) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); // Этот метод может возвращать объекты многих разных типов, поэтому возвращаемое значение необходимо преобразовать к нужному типу
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

    /***
     * Создание URL веб-сервисы openweathermap.org для названия города
     * @param city - Город, для которого ищется погодный прогноз
     * @return URL
     */
    private URL createURL(String city) {
        String apiKey = getString(R.string.api_key);
        String baseUrl = getString(R.string.web_service_url);

        try {
            // Создание URL для заданного города и температурной шкалы (Фаренгейт)
            /* Параметр units может принимать значения imperial (для шкалы Фаренгейта),
            metric (для шкалы Цельсия) или standard (для шкалы Кельвина) — если параметр
            units не указан, по умолчанию используется значение standard. Параметр cnt
            определяет количество дней в прогнозе. Максимальное значение равно 16,
            значение по умолчанию равно 7 (при некорректном количестве дней возвращается
            прогноз на 7 дней). По умолчанию прогноз возвращается в формате JSON, хотя
            вы можете добавить параметр mode со значением XML или HTML, чтобы получить
            данные в формате XML или веб-страницы соответственно.*/
            String urlString = baseUrl + URLEncoder.encode(city, "UTF-8") + "&units=imperial&cnt=16&APPID=" + apiKey;
            return new URL(urlString);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null; // Некорректный URL
    }

    /* Обращение к REST-совместимому веб-сервису за погодными данными
    и сохранение данных в локальном файле HTML */
    private class GetWeatherTask
    extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, JSONObject> {
        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(URL... params) {
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;

            try {
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) params[0].openConnection(); // Для выдачи запроса достаточно открыть объект подключения
                int response = connection.getResponseCode(); // Получить код ответа от веб-сервера

                if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

                    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()))) {
                        String line;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            builder.append(line);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout),
                                R.string.read_error, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    connection.disconnect();
                    return new JSONObject(builder.toString());
                }else {
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout),
                            R.string.connect_error, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout),
                        R.string.connect_error, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                connection.disconnect(); // Закрыть HttpURLConnection
            }

            return null;
        }

        // Обработка ответа JSON и обновление ListView
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject weather) {
            if (weather != null) {
                convertJSONtoArrayList(weather); // Заполнение weatherList
                weatherArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Связать с ListView
                weatherListView.smoothScrollToPosition(0); // Прокрутить до верха
            }
        }
    }

    // Создание объектов Weather на базе JSONObject с прогнозом
    private void convertJSONtoArrayList(JSONObject forecast) {
        weatherList.clear(); // Стирание старых погодных данных

        try {
            // Получение свойства "list" JSONArray
            JSONArray list = forecast.getJSONArray("list");

            // Преобразовать каждый элемент списка в объект Weather
            for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); ++i) {
                JSONObject day = list.getJSONObject(i); // Данные за день
                // Получить JSONObject с температурами дня ("temp")
                JSONObject temperatures = day.getJSONObject("temp");

                // Получить JSONObject c описанием и значком ("weather")
                JSONObject weather = day.getJSONArray("weather").getJSONObject(0);

                // Добавить новый объект Weather в weatherList
                weatherList.add(new Weather(
                        day.getLong("dt"), // Временная метка даты/времени
                        temperatures.getDouble("min"), // Мин. температура
                        temperatures.getDouble("max"), // Макс. температура
                        day.getDouble("humidity"), // Процент влажности
                        weather.getString("description"), // Погодные условия
                        weather.getString("icon"))); // Имя значка
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

WeatherArrayAdapter.java:

```
// Объект ArrayAdapter для отображения элементов List<Weather> в ListView
package ru.rarescrap.educationweatherview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter; // Родительский класс
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

class WeatherArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Weather> {
    // Класс для повторного использования представлений списка при прокрутке
    private static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView conditionImageView;
        TextView dayTextView;
        TextView lowTextView;
        TextView hiTextView;
        TextView humidityTextView;
    }

    // Кэш для уже загруженных объектов Bitmap
    private Map<String, Bitmap> bitmaps = new HashMap<>();

    // Конструктор для инициализации унаследованных членов суперкласса
    public WeatherArrayAdapter(Context context, List<Weather> forecast) {
        /*
        в первом и третьем аргументах передаются объект Context (то есть активность,
        в которой отображается ListView) и List<Weather> (список выводимых данных).
        Второй аргумент конструктора суперкласса представляет идентификатор ресурса
        макета, содержащего компонент TextView, в котором отображаются данные ListView.
        Аргумент –1 означает, что в приложении используется пользовательский макет,
        чтобы элемент списка не ограничивался одним компонентом TextView.
         */
        super(context, -1, forecast);
    }

    // Создание пользовательских представлений для элементов ListView
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Получение объекта Weather для заданной позиции ListView
        Weather day = getItem(position);

        //Объект, содержащий ссылки на представления элемента списка
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        // Проверить возможность повторного использования ViewHolder для элемента, вышедшего за границы экрана
        if (convertView == null) { // Объекта ViewHolder нет, создать его
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false); // последнем аргументе передается флаг автоматического присоединения представлений
            viewHolder.conditionImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.conditionImageView);
            viewHolder.dayTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dayTextView);
            viewHolder.lowTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lowTextView);
            viewHolder.hiTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.hiTextView);
            viewHolder.humidityTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.humidityTextView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else { // Cуществующий объект ViewHolder используется заново
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // Если значок погодных условий уже загружен, использовать его;
        // в противном случае загрузить в отдельном потоке
        if (bitmaps.containsKey(day.iconURL)) {
            viewHolder.conditionImageView.setImageBitmap(
            bitmaps.get(day.iconURL));
        }else {
            // Загрузить и вывести значок погодных условий
            new LoadImageTask(viewHolder.conditionImageView).execute(day.iconURL);
        }

        // Получить данные из объекта Weather и заполнить представления
        Context context = getContext(); // Для загрузки строковых ресурсов
        // Назначается текст компонентов TextView элемента ListView
        viewHolder.dayTextView.setText(context.getString(R.string.day_description, day.dayOfWeek, day.description)); // Первый аргумент - строка; Второй - аргументы для форматирования
        viewHolder.lowTextView.setText(context.getString(R.string.low_temp, day.minTemp));
        viewHolder.hiTextView.setText(context.getString(R.string.high_temp, day.maxTemp));
        viewHolder.humidityTextView.setText(context.getString(R.string.humidity, day.humidity));

        return convertView; // Вернуть готовое представление элемента
    }

    // TODO: Как полученное изображение присваивается viewHolder и представлению?
    // Кажись, изменение imageView так же изменяет и аргумент, переданный в конструкторе LoadImageTask(). Таким образом, создается нечно вроде "ссылки"
    // AsyncTask для загрузки изображения в отдельном потоке
    private class LoadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        private ImageView imageView; // Для вывода миниатюры

        // Сохранение ImageView для загруженного объекта Bitmap
        public LoadImageTask(ImageView imageView) {
            this.imageView = imageView;
        }

        // загрузить изображение; params[0] содержит URL-адрес изображения
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]); // Создать URL для изображения

                // Открыть объект HttpURLConnection, получить InputStream
                // и загрузить изображение
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // Преобразование типа необходимо, потому что метод возвращает URLConnection

                try (InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream()) {
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                    bitmaps.put(params[0], bitmap); // Кэширование
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally { // Этот участок кода будет выполняться независимо от того, какие исключения были возбуждены и перехвачены
                connection.disconnect(); // Закрыть HttpURLConnection
            }

            return bitmap;
        }

        // Связать значок погодных условий с элементом списка
        // Выполняется в потоке GUI вроде как для вывода изображения
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

Weather.java:

```
package ru.rarescrap.educationweatherview;

// Используются для преобразования временной метки каждого дня в название дня недели
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

class Weather {
    // объекты String в Java неизменяемы (immutable), поэтому несмотря на такое объявление, их значения измениться не могут
    public final String dayOfWeek;
    public final String minTemp;
    public final String maxTemp;
    public final String humidity;
    public final String description;
    public final String iconURL;

    // Конструктор
    public Weather(long timeStamp, double minTemp, double maxTemp, double humidity, String description, String iconName) {
        // NumberFormat для форматирования температур в целое число
        NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();
        numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(0); // Запрещает числа почле запятой

        this.dayOfWeek = convertTimeStampToDay(timeStamp); // Получение названия дня недели и инициализации dayOfWeek
        this.minTemp = numberFormat.format(minTemp) + "\u00B0F"; // Минимальная температура по Фаренгейту
        this.maxTemp = numberFormat.format(maxTemp) + "\u00B0F"; // Максимальная температура по Фаренгейту
        this.humidity = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance().format(humidity / 100.0);
        this.description = description; // Инициализирует описание погодных условий
        this.iconURL = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + iconName + ".png"; // Изображение погодных условий для погоды
    }

    // Преобразование временной метки в название дня недели (Monday, ...)
    private static String convertTimeStampToDay(long timeStamp) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); // Объект Calendar
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(timeStamp * 1000); // Получение времени
        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault(); // Часовой пояс устройства

        // Поправка на часовой пояс устройства
        calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, tz.getOffset( calendar.getTimeInMillis() ));

        // Объект SimpleDateFormat, возвращающий название дня недели
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE"); // EEEE - первый четыре буквы для недели
        return dateFormatter.format(calendar.getTime());
    }
}
```

Если вам не удобно читать код тут, я выложил его на гитхаб для вас:
https://github.com/RareScrap/EducationWeatherView/tree/for_stackOverFlw

Всю голову уже сломал над этой проблемой. Заранее спасибо!

**UPDATE 1**:
Если верить [этому треду](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15022727/arrayadapter-notifydatasetchanged-is-not-working), то проблем причин у нас может быть несколько

1. Адаптер теряет ссылку на список. Я прошелся отладчиком по всей проге и этот вариант отпадает. На скрине ниже показывается одинаковый номер в объекте листа и листа адаптера (насколько я могу судить, это означает что ссылка одна и та же)
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. В адаптер постоянно добавляется новый список. Понятие не имею как это мешает моей задаче. буду благодарен за объяснения.
3. Данные добавляются в адаптер до их фактического добавления в лист. Инфа 100, что такого нет. Потому что я просто не могу увидеть это :Р

**UPDATE 2**
Предпринял радикальную меру: взял код из мануала и просто копипастнул в моей проект - не заработало. Очевидно, что ошибка не в коде, т.к. пример из мануала работает как нужно. **У проблемы ноги растут из Gradle'а!** Готов поспорить что при переходе на новую версию градла некоторые вещи перестали работать. Завтра попробую покопаться откатить градл-скрипт и посмотрим что из этого выйдет. Это не первый раз, когда из-за апдейта градла у меня вылезают непредсказуемые ошибки. Где хоть найти чейжлог с изменениями при каждом обновлении?

**UPDATE 3**:
С откаченным градлом все работает. Вот только пространство имен app в xml разметках более не работает.

**UPDATE 4**:
Проблема была в разметке.

Comment: не подскажешь что эт за книга мнеб очень хотелось почитать

Comment: Алёёё Друг )я с тобй )

Comment: Адроид для разработчиков от Дейтелов 3 издание

Comment: Нашел )Спасибо,Хорошо описывается процесс?

Comment: Очень хорошо, но многие вещи мне кажется непонятными. + приложения, которые там создаются имеют minimumApiLevel 23, что не есть хорошо. Обеспечение совместимости с более старыми версиями - это долго и "весело"

Comment: Если на ваш проект таким образом влияет обновление gradle, то с ним  (проектом) что то не так

Comment: Вот только что именно с ним не так? К сожалению, мне пока не хватает опыта определить что я делаю не так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина проблемы не в коде и не в Gradle-скриптах, а **в разметке**!

Список не выводился потому, что в android:layout_height текстового поля стоял much_parent. Из-за этого текстовое поле полностью занимало все пространство экрана, сжимая список в высоте до нуля. Т.к. вывести элементы в список с такое высотой нельзя, то имено поэтому и не вызывался getView() адаптера. Исправив android:layout_height текстового поля на wrap_content, я наконец-то увидел мои элементы в списке

**!!!ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО ПРОВЕРЯЙТЕ СВОИ ФАЙЛЫ РАЗМЕТКИ И НЕ ПОВТОРЯЙТЕ МОИХ ОШИБОК!!!**

Исправленный код разметки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="ru.rarescrap.educationweatherview.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/locationEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_text"
            android:maxLines="1" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/weatherListView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Проблема в том, что когда вы получили данные, распарсили их и записали в `weatherList`, вы не создаёте заново адаптер. Он так и остаётся у вас пустым - созданным в самом начале ещё без данных.
Вы думали, что адаптер обновит информацию путём вызова метода

```
weatherArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Связать с ListView
```

но на самом деле, этот метод `notifyDataSetChanged` только **обновляет информацию для имеющихся items**, а у вас их ещё нет (список-то пустой был, когда создавался).
вместо этой строки

```
weatherArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

сделайте

```
weatherArrayAdapter = new WeatherArrayAdapter(this, weatherList);
weatherListView.setAdapter(weatherArrayAdapter);
```

Кстати, из метода `onCreate` создание адаптера этими строками можно убрать, никакой пользы они там не несут.

Удачи )

Comment: По хорошему нужно, но в мануале говорится что имя файла разметки передавать не нужно, т.к. вместо него в супере идет аргумент -1, который означает, что в приложении используется пользовательский макет, чтобы элемент списка не ограничивался одним компонентом TextView. Посмотрите конструктор класса ArrayListAdapter.

Comment: Хорошо, в супере пусть будет -1
Но вам в любом случае нужно надуть свою разметку, отдать её холдеру, он найдёт свои элементы, и затем уже при получении элементов будут расставляться значения. А у вас этого нет.

Comment: А нет, всё есть, не увидел сразу. Значит проблема не с разметкой а со списком, наверно. Щас подумаю.

Comment: Нашёл ошибку, сейчас исправлю ответ. Пару минут

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное. Жду.

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали, но это не помогло. getView Все так же не вызывается

Компилятор выругался на ваш пример. Заменил на:
weatherArrayAdapter = new WeatherArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, weatherList);
weatherListView.setAdapter(weatherArrayAdapter);

Comment: И оно все еще продолжает не работать

Comment: А точно лист не пустой?

Comment: Точно, проверил трижды на разных запросах

Comment: Я запустил у себя, у меня точно работает. Но weatherList я создал вручную, без гсона. У вас в блок onPostExecute(JSONObject weather) возвращается null. Я уверен в этом почти на 100%. Из за блока if (weather != null) ничего не происходит. Попробуйте добавить в логи else {
                Log.d("custom", "weather is null!");
            }

Comment: У меня null не возвращается. Тело If выполняется, а логи закономерно ничего не пишется. Может быть вам попробовать сделать git clone репозитория, который я написал выше? А то мне кажется, что таким макаром мы вряд ли доберемся до решения

Comment: Надеюсь, что вы мне поможете сегодня. Я третий день уже воюю с этой проблемой.

Comment: К сожалению больше помочь ничем не могу (( Тщательно логгируйте каждую строку, ищите почему массив пустой или не обрабатывается. Возможно, где то падает в try-catche. Попробуйте сначала отобразить list с вручную созданным массивом.

Comment: Я понял в чем ошибка. Пожалуйста прочтите update 2

Comment: Проблема была в разметке. Теперь у меня все заработало. Большое вам спасибо за помощь :)